# Input: two natural numbers n, m ∈ N₀ - Output: Number of different digits of the decimal representations of n and m

Tags: haskell, recursion

I got the task with the following informations:

- Input: two natural numbers n, m ∈ N₀
- Output: Number of different digits of the decimal representations of n and m

Input: two natural numbers n,k Output: digit at the 2^k digit of the binary representation of n

My idea was that:

```
stelle :: Int -> Int -> Int
stelle n 0 = mod n 2
stelle n k = stelle (div n 2) (k-1)
stelle n k = n k <= O = error
```

With the last line, haskell shows that there is a mistake. With the line is want to shwo that n and k must be natural numbers, so if n, k <= 0 theh the code is not avaible. Can somebody help me by that?

My second try is this:

```
stelle :: Int -> Int -> Int                                  
stelle n 0 = mod n 2                                         
stelle n k
| n < 0 && k < 0 = error "Vorraussetzung nicht erfüllt" 
| n >= 0 && k >= 0 = (div n 2) (k-1)
```

Comment: The assignment is contradicting: "_Number of different digits of the decimal representations of n and m_" is not the same as "_digit at the 2^k digit of the binary representation of n_".

Comment: Would you edit your question title to actually name the problem you are solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with guards like:

```
stelle :: Int -> Int -> Int
stelle n k | n < 0 || k < O = error "Vorraussetzung nicht erfüllt"
stelle n 0 = mod n 2
stelle n k = stelle (div n 2) (k-1)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks I tryed a few times and then this function:

Comment: stelle :: Int -> Int -> Int
stelle n 0 = mod n 2
stelle n k 
    | n < 0 || k < 0 = error "Vorraussetzung nicht erfüllt" 
    | n >= 0 && k >= 0 = stelle (div n 2) (k-1)

Comment: @xx33xx44: since `stelle n 0 = ...` is put first, it will also "fire" that rule if `n` is less than `0`. You also don't need to add an extra guard. You can add `stelle n k` and it will only "fire" if no previous rule was "fired".